# How can I generate my EF Mapping classes from the database using EF6.1

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

Up until now I have been using the EF Power Tools beta to do this. I click on an empty project, select EF and then reverse engineer.

The PowerTools creates all the model tables and EF mapping tables for me. It's something I do quite often when our database changes and I need to see how the mapping classes have changed.  It's not completely necessary but it saves a lot of work and makes life very easy.

From what I understand is this was added to EF6.1.  However where ...  ?

All I see from the demos is that now I have the ability to start from a database and generate code first. For this it seems I would have to create a new application and do a lot more. I miss the two click functionality of not being able to create the mapping tables.

Does anyone know if this is still available and if I just missed it. If not available then time to go back to EF Power Tools beta :-(

Comment: From what I read I think you should switch to database first (with edmx) and frequently update the model from the database.

Comment: @Gert. We are not using edmx. With the EF Power Tools reverse Engineer was a dropdown from the Context menu after you click over a project. Hopefully this functionality has not gone away as I have seen many people doing this in videos as a way to quickly get all the model and mapping definitions created automatically.

Comment: Yes, I know, but in fact you seem to work database-first, because you modify the database and the model follows. So I think you better start using an edmx. I know that in EF 6.1 the various ways to create a model have been unified in one wizard, but I don't have hands-on experience yet.

Comment: Maybe take a look at [this one](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee4fcff9-0c4c-4179-afd9-7a2fb90f5838).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the EF 6.1 Tools from MS downloads, and add a new "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" to your project, and you will have the new option to generate "Code First from database" https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Tooling%20Consolidation

Comment: He has the option.  His complaint was that he has to regenerate the entire model, rather than just his mapping classes like he could in EF Power Tools.

Comment: he can do that with 6.1 Tools

Comment: ErikEJ - Do you happen to have a link to the EF 6.1 tools? Just wondering. Any idea why they just didn't include the functionality in EF 6.1 and why another download is needed for tools ? BTW here's what I got from the download site: "Sorry, no results found for: entity framework 6.1 tools"

Comment: You do not need the updated tools for Code First. Download from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=40762

Comment: @ErikEJ - I downloaded and installed and I can still see no way to reverse engineer. In fact I can't find any information on what the power tools actually do. Maybe I am missing something obvious but where's the documentation and how do I do reverse engineer. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. I tried this. This seems to work but it's a shame for me that it does not create a different mapping file for each class and the only mapping information there is for the relationships. I will try to stick with the EF PowerTools beta at least that's still working.

Comment: Maybe look at EF Reverse POCO template, þhen?